# Coefficients that make $p(x)=(a_1x+b_1)^3+(a_2x+b_2)^3+(a_3x+b_3)^3+(a_4x+b_4)^3-x$ a constant

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

> Find integers $a_i$ and $b_i$, $i=1,2,3,4$, such that $p(x)$ is a constant function: 
>   $$p(x)=(a_1x+b_1)^3+(a_2x+b_2)^3+(a_3x+b_3)^3+(a_4x+b_4)^3-x.$$

I don't even know if such coefficients exist or not. There are 8 unknowns and they satisfy 3 equations. So it is very likely that there are integer solutions. Knowledge from number theory or algebraic geometry may be used in this problem. Another way to solve this problem is to use computer programming to check all possible integers, say, in $[-10000, 10000]$. If you can show such coefficients exist, that's also good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p(x)$ is a constant iff $p^{\prime}(x)=0$ iff

$3(a_1x+b_1)^2\cdot a_1+3(a_2x+b_2)^2\cdot a_2+3(a_3x+b_3)^2\cdot a_3+3(a_4x+b_4)^2\cdot a_4=1$ for all $x$,

and this has no integer solutions since $3\nmid 1$.

Comment: Aren't your forgetting to multiply all the terms by $a_1,a_2,...$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Yes, I sure did -- thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Since the coefficient of $x$ in $p(x)$ has to be $0$, one has
$$3a_1b_1^2+3a_2b_2^2+3a_3b_3^2+3a_4b_4^2=1.$$
Now the LHS is a multiple of $3$ while the RHS is not.

Comment: That is not all that needs to be said.  You also  need that the other coefficients, for x^3 and x^2, are 0.

Comment: @user247327: The answer shows that there are no integers $a_i,b_i$ such that the coefficient of $x$ in $p(x)$ is $0$. It follows from this that there are no integers $a_i,b_i$ such that $p(x)$ is a constant function.